# Orthogonal on an ellipse

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, conic-sections, matrix-equations, nonlinear-system

Consider two points $a \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^2$ on the boundary of an ellipse such that $a^\top \Sigma^{-1} a = b^\top \Sigma^{-1} b$. I am trying to understand which points on the boundary of this ellipse satisfy $a^\top \Sigma^{-1} b = 0$. One possibility for this to happen is when $a \perp v_1$ and $b \perp v_2$, where $v_1$ and $v_2$ are eigenvectors of $\Sigma$, then $a^\top \Sigma^{-1} b = 0$. It is also clear that if $a$ and $b$ are valid, then $(-a, b), (a, -b) \text{ and } (-a, -b)$ are also valid solutions. Is it possible to find other points on the boundary of the ellipse such $a^\top \Sigma^{-1} b = 0$ or show that no other points besides these four exist, where this condition is satisfied ?

Comment: What is the equation of the ellipse ? (In fact, you didn't give it.)

Comment: $x^\top \Sigma^{-1} x = c$, for some constant $c$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that $\Sigma$ is symmetric postive definite. Let $R$ be the rotation $$R = \begin{pmatrix}0 & -1 \\[1 ex] 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$ Take any vector $b \neq 0$ and $$a = \Sigma ^{1/2} R \Sigma ^{-1/2} b.$$
Then $$a^{\mathrm t} \Sigma^{-1} a = b^{\mathrm t} \Sigma^{-1} b$$ and $$a^{\textrm t}\Sigma^{-1}b=0.$$

Comment: Your R corresponds to a $90^\circ$ rotation. If I start with $a$ and $b$ along the eigenvectors, I will not get anything different from the 4 pairs.

Comment: You can take an arbitrary $b$ on the ellipse though.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the simplest case:  ${\bf \Sigma} = {\bf I}$ (the identity matrix):

[image]

Here's what you get with ${\bf \Sigma} \neq {\bf I}$:

[image]

Clear?

Comment: Just edited the question. I want to know if there are points besides the 4 obvious points that satisfy $a^\top \Sigma^{-1}b = 0$